# Python XGBoost classifier can't `predict`: `TypeError: Not supported type for data`

Tags: python, typeerror, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I have a dataset like so:

```
print(X_test.dtypes)
metric1                    int64
rank                     float64
device_type                 int8
NA_estimate              float64
```

When I try to make predictions on this data set, I get the following error:

```
y_test_pred_xgb = clf_xgb.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X_test))
TypeError: Not supported type for data.<class 'xgboost.core.DMatrix'>
```

I searched for a bit but only found discussion of `object` variable data types causing issues. Is there something else wrong with my data or is the issue something else? I have looked at various blogs and Kaggle code without luck.

Comment: Source code suggests your types are fine (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/e7d17ec4f4a091bac58c1d241be3f4969400b874/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L220) but maybe try `as.type()` to change int8 to int64? Also check that you only have numeric values in your numeric variables

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and solved it by casting the data type using `np.float32()`:

```
model.predict(np.float32(X_test))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Your `clf_xgb` model object is an implementation of Scikit-Learn API. `DMatrix` is an internal data structure that is used by XGBoost. Maybe this caused the [problem](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/8757#issuecomment-1419554422).

You can try with:

```
clf_xgb.get_booster().predict(xgb.DMatrix(X_test))
```

In my case, this worked.